# How to show listbox added items count in Label?

Tags: c#

[image: Workshop Selector GUI]

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int gTotal = 1;


    for (int gCount = 0; gCount < listBox3.Items.Count - 1; gCount++)

    gTotal += (listBox3.Items.Add(gCount));

    label1.Text = gTotal.ToString();
}
```

Hey guys i'm not entirely sure of how to use Listboxes, but my question is how can I display the numbers that populate in my list box 3 to go into the label?

Comment: `(listBox3.Items.Add(gCount));` doesn't do what you think

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: what is `gTotal ` supposed to calculate/represent ?=!

Comment: `listBox3.Items.Add` returns the index of the added item. So you would integrate/accumulate the indices.

Comment: The variable to hold the costs of the workshops and locations all added up together.

Comment: How would I integrate or accumulate the indices?

Comment: I still don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. How do you calculate the costs? simply by the index? the first is 0 the second 1 ... ?=!

Comment: I'm trying to add the numbers that are in listbox 3 up and them have them appear in the total label.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int gTotal = 1;
    var collection = listBox3.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

    for (int gCount = 0; gCount < collection.Count - 1; gCount++)
    {
        int item;
        if (int.TryParse(collection[gCount], out item)
        {
            gTotal += item;
        }
    }

    label1.Text = gTotal.ToString();
}
```

Cast the items to a List then make sure that items are ints, if so add them up.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your items.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int gTotal = 1;

    for (int gCount = 0; gCount < listBox3.Items.Count; gCount++)
         gTotal += int.Parse(listBox3.Items[gCount].ToString()); 
         // assuming all items in the listbox is an int.

    label1.Text = gTotal.ToString();
}
```

[What trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPCub.png)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but based on your UI you should put the total inside a textbox and not a label.

Comment: Program calls for a label, but I guess what I'm trying to figure out is how to add items up in a listbox and appear in a label.